# Proving that a polynomial is bounded on bounded domains

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

> **Definition:** A real function $f:X\to\mathbb{R}$ is said to be bounded if there exists a $k>0$ such that $|f(x)|\le k$
>
> **Definition**: A subset $X$ of a metric space $(M, d)$ is said to be bounded if $d(x,y)\le c$ for all $x,y\in X$.

Let $p:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ a real polynomial function of degree $n>0$ given by
$$
p(t) = a_0 + a_1t+ \cdots + a_nt^n
$$
Show that $p$ is not bounded. Moreover, show that for every bounded subset $X\subset\mathbb{R}$, the restriction $s:X\to \mathbb{R}, s(t) = p(t)$ is bounded.

Comment: The word is **bounded**, not "limited".

Comment: You want $s: X \to \mathbb R$, not $X \to X$.  There is no reason to think that $p(t) \in X$ for $t \in X$.